# Changing web host: want to change domain name, but want to forward users to new domain

Tags: domains, dns

I'm moving to a new web host, so totally new IP. At the same time, I want to change my domain name from xyz.org to xyz.net (it's a non profit website that several hundred people use, but there's no organization. It's just me, so the '.org' is a bit of a misnomer). If people continue to go to xyz.org, I'd like them to be automatically redirected to xyz.net. Also, I'd like a way to detect, via server-side php or javascript in the client browser, that they've been forwarded and put up a message like 'Yo dude, start using the new URL: xyz.net'

I'd prefer to do all this while not having to pay to the original webhost to keep my xyz.org site running so it can forward users using traditional http forwarding methods. So can this forwarding be done any other way? Can a DNS registry service do this forwarding for me? Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

This is all quite straight forward.

- Register your new domain and get the site going at the new host.
- Add the old domain to the DNS on your new host.
- Change the nameservers on the old domain to your new host
- At your new host add a redirect from the old domain to the new domain

There are numerous ways of detecting that the visitor has come via the old domain.  Coding is off topic on this site, but if it were me, I would redirect the old domain to `xyz.net?redirect=true` (or whatever suits you) and then on the new site using PHP parse the querystring and act accordingly.

Comment: I am a little confused by your answer. This requires that sites example.org and example.net both are created and hosted as websites where one is redirected to the other. DNS cannot redirect anything. (I assume you know this, just stating it for the OP.) However, if a catch-all site, the first site created on the server, exists then it is possible to use the catch-all site to capture all unknown traffic and redirect it to the preferred site. This assumes that the OP is not one of many sites on a shared server. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc - where do you see that I am suggesting DNS does the redirecting?  Not at all.  It would be a .htaccess redirect.  That's why I suggested getting the old domain's DNS to the new host.

Comment: I am not. I was just putting it in with the assumption it could be possible the OP may be thinking that is what you meant. It was a JIC/CYA statement for the OP. Sorry for the confusion. What is most important is that the OP know that both sites have to exist on the webserver in some form. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc where would we be without confusion?

Comment: I would probably be at home watching TV instead of wandering the streets of the next town wondering where my house went!

Comment: Just to add, if you use the URL param approach to record the redirect, make sure you set the `rel="canonical"` or "ignore" the URL param in GSC - as you don't want that getting indexed. However, if the DNS has been updated so that the old domain points to the new host then you should see the 301 redirect in the server access log at the new host.

Comment: Thanks folks.  I'm more of a GIS developer than a web master, so some of this is a bit hard to understand.  But I think I have enough information to proceed. @cosetnoc, I see what you're saying. If this is too much of a pain, I'm gonna watch TV at home